# Letter Q stopped working on keyboard

Tags: keyboard

Letter <kbd>Q</kbd> and <kbd>q</kbd> stopped working on my keyboard.  (I had to find an ASCII chart to copy and paste the character.)  I really have no clue what's going on.

xev produces the following output.

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x2d0, subw 0x0, time 405078, (133,92), root:(684,389),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

MotionNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4600001,
    root 0x2d0, subw 0x0, time 405086, (129,92), root:(680,389),
    state 0x0, is_hint 0, same_screen YES

I tested ever character on my keyboard with & without a shift in the command line.  They all seem to work fine.
erm@erm:/etc$ abcdefghijklmnoprstuvwxyz1234567890!@#$%^&*()_+-=WERTYUIOP{}[]\|ASDFGHJKL:";'ZXCVVBNM<>,.?/`~
```

So for trouble shooting I plugged in a usb keyboard and <kbd>q</kbd> and <kbd>Q</kbd> work.  Any ideas?

```
KeyRelease event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x4800001,
    root 0x2d0, subw 0x0, time 1829129, (-168,89), root:(383,386),
    state 0x0, keycode 24 (keysym 0x71, q), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (71) "q"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: Do they work in a text console?

Comment: I presed ctr+alt+f1 and logged in there.  It doesn't work there either.  Oh a whim I opened up keyboard settings and created a hotkey to see what it was reporting.  Oddly it's reporting `XF86Suspend`

Comment: Try if works on console close all consoles,open one and try.
If not try

    loadkeys yourlang
    setxkbmap yourlang

of course yourlang can be us,en,it,etc
If doesn't work can be a keyboard problem,is a laptop or desktop?

Comment: To test if it's a hardware problem, take Unix/Linux out of the picture: try booting into grub, choose `e` to edit a line, and try typing your `q` key there.

Comment: Ok fun stuff.  I edited in grub and `q` did work.  So that's good news.  It seems as though I'm the victim of a practical joke.  (Since it's trying to run `XF86Suspend` when I press Q.)  Oddly enough it's only on the laptop keyboard, and the usb keyboard is fine.